# How does one use a scanner to go through a file and take out the first line two line, leaving only the strings of words not the numbers

Tags: java

```
2
3
1 2 3 4 5 5
3 4 5 6 7 5
4 5 1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9
2
10 11 15 61 42 14 112 34
12 13 11 61 42 10 34 12 14 112
```

> I currently have this, the file is for the set above.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"));
    int totalSets = scan.nextInt();
    int nest = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();
    while(scan.hasNextLine() && totalSets-->=0) {
    Set<String> lines = new HashSet<String>();
    lines.add(scan.nextLine());
    System.out.println(lines);}


    while(scan.hasNextLine() && nest-->=1) {
        Set<String> lines = new HashSet<String>();
        lines.add(scan.nextLine());
        System.out.println(lines);}
```

> So in my code it keeps returning the 2, within the set. I was wondering why this happens if if someone could help me figure it out.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What does that have to do with Java?

Comment: Please show us your code to see what you tried and it is also confusing please try and clarify

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this code .

```
import java.util.*;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String n = scanner.nextLine();
        for(int i =0;i<Integer.parseInt(n);i++){
            String a= scanner.nextLine();

            for(int z =0; z < Integer.parseInt(a); z++){
                System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So this returns to me the 3 and the 2. What I'm wondering is how to return everything else but those. So you kind of answered my question in reverse.

Comment: Please test with above code , It will give other part of input instead of 3 and 2.